# ASP.NET UpdatePanel - inline variable

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have a server-side variable which is assigned a value in PreRender. For the sake of simplicity, let's imagine I'm doing this:

```
    protected string test;
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

In my markup, the variable is then referred to within an UpdatePanel, like so:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Perform postback" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
                    alert('<%=test%>');
                });
            </script>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On first load of the page, the JavaScript alert function gives me a random value, as expected. However, on any subsequent postback, the original value of the Guid is retained.

Can anybody explain why this is so, and offer a solution? I'm fairly sure I can achieve the required behaviour by putting the value of 'test' in a hidden field, for example, but ideally I wouldn't have to sink to those depths. Unfortunately replacing the UpdatePanel with something lighter isn't really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to this, and nor is it quite as dirty as I'd feared. I declare a JS variable outside of the function:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Perform postback" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var test;

                Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
                    alert(test);
                });
            </script>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In my code-behind, I assign the JS variable a value in the Sys.Application.add_init method, like so:

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(UpdatePanelTest), "startupScripts", "Sys.Application.add_init(function() {test='" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "';});", true);
    }
```

Voilà, a different Guid is then displayed on first load and every postback.